# How to stop floating element to right overextending bootstrap row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm new to web dev. Using bootstrap 4 grid system.

I have a row containing a title and a breadcrumb. I want to float the breadcrumb to the right of the row, but when I do so it seems to be overextending the row, causing it to display on two lines.

How do I stop it from doing this.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<!-- PAGE TITLE AND BREADCRUMBS   -->
<div class="container" style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:0px">
  <div class="row rounded" style="background-color:#409ad4">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h1>title</h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right" style="background-color:#f5f5f5">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item" style="font-size: 19px"><a href="#">News Channels</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item" style="font-size: 19px">Prayer Channel</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Bottom container div -->
</div>
```

And here is a screen shot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: show the css that you have so far for that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the `<h1>` tag is a block level element, so by default will expand to 100% width of the parent. You might want to define 2 columns - one for the title and another for the breadcrumb.